# How to add WordPress' htaccess configurations into VirtualHost conf

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I put WordPress' configuration into my VirtualHost directive, it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory />
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I put WordPress' configuration inside VirtualHost's root directory like above, the permalink and sub domain won't work.

But when I put WordPress' configuration inside the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` root directory which is `/var/www/html` (as you can see it is the same root as Virtual host), then subdomain and permalinks are fine, I don't get it?

The reason I don't want to put WordPress' configuration in `httpd.conf` is because I want to make another site but it's not multisite, so I have to enter another [WordPress' configuration](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) on it.

- I IncludeOptional the virtual host conf file at the very bottom of `httpd.conf`
- I use CentOS 7
- Apache 2.4
- Wordpress 4.5.3
- Mod rewrite included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours it seems another rewrite rule that came **above** the `IncludeOptional path/to/virtualhost/*.conf` in `httpd.conf` had interfere Wordpress' configuration.

To troubleshoot most common permalinks or subdomains problem in wordpress is always check your rewrite rules and make sure the Wordpress rule ([that one for the .htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)) is **always** on top of the others.